# nginx and API versioning in Accept header or URL

Tags: nginx

So I have decided to do two kind of wrong, slightly inspired by [Troy Hunt](http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/02/your-api-versioning-is-wrong-which-is.html).

I would like my API to accept version specification through `Accept` header but also in the URL, e.g. `/v1`.

For now, I have made an nginx config which works with `Accept` header, but trying out various methods, I have not been able to get the `/v1`

What I want to achieve is that the URL passed to my application, does not include the version part as the role of the version is simply to point at a `root` directory.

```
map $http_accept $api_version {
    default 0;
    "application/vnd.it.echo.api+json; version=1" "v1";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.app;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    sendfile off;

rewrite_log on;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        if ($api_version = 0) {
            return 307 https://echo.it;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ @api;
    }

    location /v1 {
        set $api_version "v1";
        rewrite ^/.+/(.+)$ /$1 last;
    }

    location @api {
        root       /home/vagrant/api/$api_version/public/;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/api.$api_version.app-error.log error;
        try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /home/vagrant/api/$api_version/public/;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

The problem appears to be with the `rewrite` rule in the `/v1` location directive not taking effect.